# Google maps api V3 - zoom on mouse wheel only if ALT key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I use google map api v3 in my website: the map is width 100% and height 450px. So, when you scroll the page, it will automatically stop on the map because of the mousewheel event to zoom the map. I don't want to disable it because it's kind of a cool feature so I was looking for a way to zoom on mouse wheel only if ALT key is pressed. First, I did it with jQuery like this:

```
<div id="my_map" class="Scrollable" 
onmouseover="hover_div['my_map']=true;" onmouseout="hover_div['my_map']=false;">
```

"hover_div" is a global array defined in the head, "map" is a global variable (with "scrollwheel" set to false)

```
$('.Scrollable').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(ev) {
    if(ev.altKey && hover_div['my_map']){
        var $this = $(this),
            scrollTop = this.scrollTop,
            scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight,
            height = $this.height(),
            delta = (ev.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
                ev.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
                ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta),
            up = delta > 0;

        var prevent = function() {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

        if (!up && -delta > scrollHeight - height - scrollTop) {
            $this.scrollTop(scrollHeight);

                var mapZoom = parseFloat(map.getZoom());
                if(mapZoom > 0){
                mapZoom = mapZoom - 1;
                map.setZoom(mapZoom);
                }
            return prevent();
        } else if (up && delta > scrollTop) {
            $this.scrollTop(0);

                var mapZoom = parseFloat(map.getZoom());
                if(mapZoom < 21){
                mapZoom = mapZoom + 1;
                map.setZoom(mapZoom);
                }
            return prevent();
        }
    }
});
```

It's working, but it zoom from the center without considering the mouse position as the default event does.

I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/YFnbe/3/) who trigger the Google Maps mouse wheel event: maybe there's a way to launch the default event only if the ALT key is pressed, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: I'd recommend leaving the default Google Maps behaviour alone as mouse wheel zooming is what the user will expect.

Comment: Yes but I added a note on the map to tell that you can use alt + mousewheel to zoom. Because of the width 100%, it's very annoying that you cannot scroll the page at that point (where the map is)

Comment: I feel dumb, it was super easy: trigger the altkey and modify the map options like this "map.setOptions({ scrollwheel: true });"